# '+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil. Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'

Tags: ios, objective-c

am post mycode to json but my app error

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be
>   non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'"

```
-(void)requesdatesendorder:(NSArray *)foodid{
NSString *FoodId ;

for (int i =0; i < foodid.count; i++) {
    NSString *idfood = [foodid objectAtIndex:i];
    if (FoodId.length == 0) {
        FoodId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,food_id[%d]",idfood,i];
    }
    else{
        FoodId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,food_id[%d]",FoodId,idfood,i];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",FoodId);

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"date_send_order",@"params",
                        FoodId
                        ,nil];
[self requestWithMethod:@"POST"
              urlString:kFeedBeeservice
             parameters:params
                   mode:Beeservicedatesendorder];
}
```

but i want send json format
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkfqv.png

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do but instead of dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys use latest objC syntax params = @{ @"key" : value };

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified any key for **FoodId**. Your syntax of `NSDictionary` is wrong. It should be as follows,

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"Object1",@"key1",@"object2",@"key2",nil];
```

In your code add a key for FoodId or add an object for FoodId. It will resolve your error.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"date_send_order",@"params",
                    FoodId,@"key",nil];
```

OR

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"date_send_order",@"params",@"object"
                    FoodId,nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues I see:

Break the `for` loop as soon as you have the string:

```
NSString *foodIdStr = nil;

for (int i =0; i < foodid.count && foodIdStr == nil; i++) {
    NSString *idfood = [foodid objectAtIndex:i];
    if (FoodId.length == 0) {
        foodIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,food_id[%d]",idfood,i];
    }
    else{
        foodIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,food_id[%d]",FoodId,idfood,i];
    }
}
```

Ensure you don't assign a `nil` value to the dictionary:

```
if (foodIdStr == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get food id");
    return;
}
```

You are using the wrong number of parameters to `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"date_send_order", @"params",
    foodIdStr, @"food_id",    // Here
    nil];
```